# Header Location adds unexpected "#"

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server-configuration

I'm expecting an issue with

```
header('Location:http://www.google.com');
exit;
```

It redirects me to any kind of specified url but with "#" at the end. Please help me to find solutions.

Other info:

- php 5.3
- Wordpress 3.9.2.

p.s using the `header()`, `wp_safe_redirect()` and `wp_redirect()` return the same issue. Using header to investigate the issue in it's initial statement.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried in Chrome and FF.

Only "#" at the end.

HTACCESS:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] # <- For security porposes
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Probably a plugin, yes. Please let me know what are your suggestion to look for. I mean how plugin can affect server configuration.

P.S.2 May it be a server-side issues? Shall I contact hosting provider?

P.S.3 I've tried all possible types of URLs with and w/o space between `:` and `url_string`

P.S.4 Code is a simple if-else combination before the headers.

Comment: php won't add a `#` on you.

Comment: Probably some plugin

Comment: Just a `#` or is there more behind it?

Comment: Could it be something in your .htaccess file?

Comment: There should be a space after `Location:` in the header i.e. 
`header('Location: http://www.google.com');`

Comment: Have you tried another URL but http://www.google.com?

Comment: show the other codes of this page.  i think its some other problem . header given is correct.